# IF/THEN nested formula in EXCEL

Tags: excel

I'm having an awful time wrapping my head around an if/then formula for excel with multiple conditions featuring percentages... would anyone like to take a crack at it?

I have commission percentages that are based upon another percentage of gross margin.. so if the gross margin is 0-5% there is no commission; if the gross margin is 6-10% there is a 4% commission and so forth.  All of these conditions need to make it into 1 formula..

[image]

Comment: Show your [mcve].

Comment: You can do this with a lookup table, similar to that used to calculate taxes. But your table leaves undefined the situation where the gross margin falls between two bins.  e.g 16.5%

Answer (score 0):

I think it would make a lot more sense to store this data in excel as a table (min, max, contribution) and then use that table in a formula (instead of a horrid awful no good nested `if()` that would have to be updated any time these contributions, min or max changed).

Consider:

[image]